# Make aptitude quiet

Tags: command-line, aptitude

I'm looking for a way to make aptitude(1) be quiet when installing packages. I want it to only produce output on explicit errors. The -q option does this is most other programs, but apparently not in aptitude.

My goal is being able to say:

```
someprogram: You need to install the foobar package for this to work.

$ sudo aptitude install foobar -yq &
```

And not have the screen filled with text. I'm aware of `> /dev/null`, but that seems like an ugly way of doing what I feel should be a very common task.

Comment: The parameter `q` changes the level of quietness. The app will so output less log-messages - but I wasn't able to find any details about the max level of quietness - neither about what is not shown in what level ... See: http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`> /dev/null` is actually the *standard* way of shutting up programs.

Output redirection (whether to a file or to the bit bucket) is indeed a common task, which is why the *single-character* `>` operator was introduced in Unix shells. (In its predecesor Multics, one would have to run a separate `iocall attach ...` command before and after, to set up and remove redirections.)

Another feature that Unix shells have for performing common tasks is *scripts* and *functions*. If you just want to shorten a command, use:

```
inst() { sudo aptitude install "$@" -yq > /dev/null & }
```

which will allow you to install stuff with `inst package`.